# How to get Ads on Ruby on Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ads, adsense

I've spent the past month trying to get ads on my web app to just be told by a guy in a google forum that *Adsense* doesn't work with apps.

Is this true? Sounds strange. I couldn't find a convincing answer one way or another.

If Adsense doesn't work on *Ruby on Rails* how can I easily get ads on my app? Is there a gem? I feel like this would be a common question, but I couldn't get it answered in my google searches so I've come to you SO.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my ads approved by first using my blog [AnthonyGalli.com](http://www.anthonygalli.com/) to get approval then posting ad-sense code onto my app. I don't think this is frowned upon as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know RoR has .rb template.
You can embed your adsense code in .rb template?

Also it could just be that you have adblock on?